# Server Side Swift with Perfect authentication and routes

Tags: swift, mustache, perfect, server-side-swift

I have server side swift project that is setup to upload files. And I am attempting to authentication to the project so that the files can only be accessed with a valid login.

**main.swift**

```
import PerfectLib
import PerfectHTTP
import PerfectHTTPServer

import StORM
import SQLiteStORM
import PerfectTurnstileSQLite
import PerfectRequestLogger
import TurnstilePerfect

//StORMdebug = true

// Used later in script for the Realm and how the user authenticates.
let pturnstile = TurnstilePerfectRealm()


// Set the connection vatiable
//connect = SQLiteConnect("./authdb")
SQLiteConnector.db = "./authdb"
RequestLogFile.location = "./http_log.txt"

// Set up the Authentication table
let auth = AuthAccount()
try? auth.setup()

// Connect the AccessTokenStore
tokenStore = AccessTokenStore()
try? tokenStore?.setup()

//let facebook = Facebook(clientID: "CLIENT_ID", clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET")
//let google = Google(clientID: "CLIENT_ID", clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET")

// Create HTTP server.
let server = HTTPServer()

// Register routes and handlers
let authWebRoutes = makeWebAuthRoutes()
let authJSONRoutes = makeJSONAuthRoutes("/api/v1")

// Add the routes to the server.
server.addRoutes(authWebRoutes)
server.addRoutes(authJSONRoutes)

// Adding a test route
var routes = Routes()
var postHandle: [[String: Any]] = [[String: Any]]()
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/api/v1/test", handler: AuthHandlersJSON.testHandler)
routes.add(method: .post, uri: "/", handler: {
    request, response in

    // Context variable, which also initializes the "files" array
    var context = ["files":[[String:String]]()]

    // Process only if request.postFileUploads is populated
    if let uploads = request.postFileUploads, uploads.count > 0 {

        // iterate through the file uploads.
        for upload in uploads {

            // move file
            let thisFile = File(upload.tmpFileName)
            do {
                let _ = try thisFile.moveTo(path: "./webroot/uploads/\(upload.fileName)", overWrite: true)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    // Inspect the uploads directory contents
    let d = Dir("./webroot/uploads")
    do{
        try d.forEachEntry(closure: {f in
            context["files"]?.append(["name":f])
        })
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }


    // Render the Mustache template, with context.
     response.render(template: "index", context: context)
    response.completed()
})
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/", handler: {
    request, response in

    // Context variable, which also initializes the "files" array
    var context = ["files":[[String:String]]()]

    // Process only if request.postFileUploads is populated
    if let uploads = request.postFileUploads, uploads.count > 0 {

        // iterate through the file uploads.
        for upload in uploads {

            // move file
            let thisFile = File(upload.tmpFileName)
            do {
                let _ = try thisFile.moveTo(path: "./webroot/uploads/\(upload.fileName)", overWrite: true)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    // Inspect the uploads directory contents
    let d = Dir("./webroot/uploads")
    do{
        try d.forEachEntry(closure: {f in
            context["files"]?.append(["name":f])
        })
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    var resp = [String: String]()
    resp["authenticated"] = "AUTHED: \(request.user.authenticated)"
    // Render the Mustache template, with context.
    response.render(template: "index", context: resp)
    response.completed()
})
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/**", handler: try PerfectHTTPServer.HTTPHandler.staticFiles(data: ["documentRoot":"./webroot",
                                                                                    "allowResponseFilters":true]))


// An example route where authentication will be enforced
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/api/v1/check", handler: {
    request, response in
    response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "application/json")

    var resp = [String: String]()
    resp["authenticated"] = "AUTHED: \(request.user.authenticated)"
    resp["authDetails"] = "DETAILS: \(String(describing: request.user.authDetails))"

    do {
        try response.setBody(json: resp)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    response.completed()
})


// An example route where auth will not be enforced
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/api/v1/nocheck", handler: {
    request, response in
    response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "application/json")

    var resp = [String: String]()
    resp["authenticated"] = "AUTHED: \(request.user.authenticated)"
    resp["authDetails"] = "DETAILS: \(String(describing: request.user.authDetails))"

    do {
        try response.setBody(json: resp)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    response.completed()
})



// Add the routes to the server.
server.addRoutes(routes)


// Setup logging
let myLogger = RequestLogger()

// add routes to be checked for auth
var authenticationConfig = AuthenticationConfig()
authenticationConfig.include("/api/v1/check")
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/login")
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/register")

let authFilter = AuthFilter(authenticationConfig)

// Note that order matters when the filters are of the same priority level
server.setRequestFilters([pturnstile.requestFilter])
server.setResponseFilters([pturnstile.responseFilter])

server.setRequestFilters([(authFilter, .high)])

server.setRequestFilters([(myLogger, .high)])
server.setResponseFilters([(myLogger, .low)])

// Set a listen port of 8181
server.serverPort = 8181

// Where to serve static files from
server.documentRoot = "./webroot"

do {
    // Launch the HTTP server.
    try server.start()
} catch PerfectError.networkError(let err, let msg) {
    print("Network error thrown: \(err) \(msg)")
}
```

If I change the context: to context I get the stuck in a loop like I am not logged in even after successful login.  If I change context: to resp I get stuck in a always logged in state and I can't see the files.

```
    var resp = [String: String]()
    resp["authenticated"] = "AUTHED: \(request.user.authenticated)"
    // Render the Mustache template, with context.
    response.render(template: "index", context: resp)
    response.completed()
```

**index.mustache**

```
{{>header}}

{{^authenticated}}
<h1>Hi! Sign up today!</h1>
{{/authenticated}}
{{#authenticated}}
<h1>Hi! {{username}}</h1>
<p>Your ID is: <code>{{accountID}}</code></p>
<h2>File uploads</h2>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
File to upload: <input type="file" name="fileup"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload files now.">
</form>

<h3>Files:</h3>
{{#files}}<a href="/uploads/{{name}}">{{name}}</a><br>{{/files}}
{{/authenticated}}



{{>footer}}
```

**UPDATE**

I am close to having the site working the way I want it. The code blow shows the changes I have made and my new hurdle that I need to over come. Which is how to use two different context in the same `render`?

```
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/", handler: { request, response in

    if request.user.authenticated == true {
        guard let accountID = request.user.authDetails?.account.uniqueID else { return }

        do {
            let newDir = Dir("./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))")
            let _ = try newDir.create()
        } catch {

        }
        // Context variable, which also initializes the "files" array
        var context = ["files":[[String:String]]()]

        // Process only if request.postFileUploads is populated
        if let uploads = request.postFileUploads, uploads.count > 0 {

            // iterate through the file uploads.
            for upload in uploads {

                // move file
                let thisFile = File(upload.tmpFileName)
                do {
                    let _ = try thisFile.moveTo(path: "./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))/\(upload.fileName)", overWrite: true)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        // Inspect the uploads directory contents
        let d = Dir("./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))")
        do{
            try d.forEachEntry(closure: {f in
                context["files"]?.append(["name":f])
            })
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        let setID = [["accountID": accountID]]
        var dic = [String: String]()
        for item in setID {
            for (kind, value) in item {
                dic.updateValue(value, forKey: kind)
            }
        }

        var context1 = ["files":String()]
        context1.updateValue(accountID, forKey: "accountID")
        // Render the Mustache template, with context.
        response.render(template: "loggedin", context: context) // I only get this context info. 
        response.render(template: "loggedin", context: context1) // This is ignored unless I comment out the line above. 
        response.completed()

    } else {
        response.render(template: "index")
        response.completed()

    }
})
```

Also changed this section of code.

```
var authenticationConfig = AuthenticationConfig()
authenticationConfig.include("/api/v1/check")
authenticationConfig.include("/loggedin") // Added this line
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/login")
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/register")
```

Comment: have you looked at the demo here?
https://github.com/PerfectExamples/Perfect-Turnstile-SQLite-Demo Might be a good starting point. I think you're missing a few components but without seeing your structure it's hard to gauge sorry. Thx, Jono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based off the [Perfect-Turnstile-SQLite-Demo](https://github.com/PerfectExamples/Perfect-Turnstile-SQLite-Demo) and parts of this project [File-Uploads](https://github.com/PerfectExamples/File-Uploads).  The objective was to create a Swift Server Side application that based on the users login it would create a private directory for the user to upload files.

**main.swift**

```
//
//  main.swift
//  PerfectTurnstileSQLiteDemo
//
//  Created by Jonathan Guthrie on 2016-10-11.
//  Copyright (C) 2015 PerfectlySoft, Inc.
//
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
//
// This source file is part of the Perfect.org open source project
//
// Copyright (c) 2015 - 2016 PerfectlySoft Inc. and the Perfect project authors
// Licensed under Apache License v2.0
//
// See http://perfect.org/licensing.html for license information
//
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
//

import PerfectLib
import PerfectHTTP
import PerfectHTTPServer

import StORM
import SQLiteStORM
import PerfectTurnstileSQLite
import PerfectRequestLogger
import TurnstilePerfect

//StORMdebug = true

// Used later in script for the Realm and how the user authenticates.
let pturnstile = TurnstilePerfectRealm()


// Set the connection vatiable
//connect = SQLiteConnect("./authdb")
SQLiteConnector.db = "./authdb"
RequestLogFile.location = "./http_log.txt"


// Set up the Authentication table
let auth = AuthAccount()
try? auth.setup()

// Connect the AccessTokenStore
tokenStore = AccessTokenStore()
try? tokenStore?.setup()

//let facebook = Facebook(clientID: "CLIENT_ID", clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET")
//let google = Google(clientID: "CLIENT_ID", clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET")

// Create HTTP server.
let server = HTTPServer()

// Register routes and handlers
let authWebRoutes = makeWebAuthRoutes()
let authJSONRoutes = makeJSONAuthRoutes("/api/v1")

// Add the routes to the server.
server.addRoutes(authWebRoutes)
server.addRoutes(authJSONRoutes)

// Adding a test route
var routes = Routes()
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/api/v1/test", handler: AuthHandlersJSON.testHandler)
routes.add(method: .post, uri: "/", handler: {
    request, response in


    if request.user.authenticated == true {
        guard let accountID = request.user.authDetails?.account.uniqueID else { return }

        do {
            let newDir = Dir("./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))")
            let _ = try newDir.create()
        } catch {

        }
        // Context variable, which also initializes the "files" array
        var context = ["files":[[String:String]]()]

        // Process only if request.postFileUploads is populated
        if let uploads = request.postFileUploads, uploads.count > 0 {

            // iterate through the file uploads.
            for upload in uploads {

                // move file
                let thisFile = File(upload.tmpFileName)
                do {
                    let _ = try thisFile.moveTo(path: "./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))/\(upload.fileName)", overWrite: true)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        // Inspect the uploads directory contents
        let d = Dir("./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))")
        do{
            try d.forEachEntry(closure: {f in
                context["files"]?.append(["name":f])
            })
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        context["files"]?.append(["aID":accountID])
        // Render the Mustache template, with context.
        response.render(template: "loggedin", context: context)
        response.completed()

    } else {
        response.render(template: "index")
        response.completed()

    }
})
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/", handler: { request, response in

    if request.user.authenticated == true {
        guard let accountID = request.user.authDetails?.account.uniqueID else { return }

        do {
            let newDir = Dir("./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))")
            let _ = try newDir.create()
        } catch {

        }
        // Context variable, which also initializes the "files" array
        var context = ["files":[[String:String]]()]

        // Process only if request.postFileUploads is populated
        if let uploads = request.postFileUploads, uploads.count > 0 {

            // iterate through the file uploads.
            for upload in uploads {

                // move file
                let thisFile = File(upload.tmpFileName)
                do {
                    let _ = try thisFile.moveTo(path: "./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))/\(upload.fileName)", overWrite: true)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        // Inspect the uploads directory contents
        let d = Dir("./webroot/uploads/\(String(describing: accountID))")
        do{
            try d.forEachEntry(closure: {f in
                context["files"]?.append(["name":f])
            })
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        context["files"]?.append(["aID":accountID])
        // Render the Mustache template, with context.
        response.render(template: "loggedin", context: context)
        response.completed()

    } else {
        response.render(template: "index")
        response.completed()

    }
})
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/**", handler: try PerfectHTTPServer.HTTPHandler.staticFiles(data: ["documentRoot":"./webroot", "allowResponseFilters":true]))

// An example route where authentication will be enforced
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/api/v1/check", handler: {
    request, response in
    response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "application/json")

    var resp = [String: String]()
    resp["authenticated"] = "AUTHED: \(request.user.authenticated)"
    resp["authDetails"] = "DETAILS: \(String(describing: request.user.authDetails))"

    do {
        try response.setBody(json: resp)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    response.completed()
})


// An example route where auth will not be enforced
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/api/v1/nocheck", handler: {
    request, response in
    response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "application/json")

    var resp = [String: String]()
    resp["authenticated"] = "AUTHED: \(request.user.authenticated)"
    resp["authDetails"] = "DETAILS: \(String(describing: request.user.authDetails))"

    do {
        try response.setBody(json: resp)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    response.completed()
})



// Add the routes to the server.
server.addRoutes(routes)

// Setup logging
let myLogger = RequestLogger()

// add routes to be checked for auth
var authenticationConfig = AuthenticationConfig()
authenticationConfig.include("/api/v1/check")
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/login")
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/register")

let authFilter = AuthFilter(authenticationConfig)

// Note that order matters when the filters are of the same priority level
server.setRequestFilters([pturnstile.requestFilter])
server.setResponseFilters([pturnstile.responseFilter])

server.setRequestFilters([(authFilter, .high)])

server.setRequestFilters([(myLogger, .high)])
server.setResponseFilters([(myLogger, .low)])

// Set a listen port of 8181
server.serverPort = 8181

// Where to serve static files from
server.documentRoot = "./webroot"

do {
    // Launch the HTTP server.
    try server.start()
} catch PerfectError.networkError(let err, let msg) {
    print("Network error thrown: \(err) \(msg)")
}
```

**header.mustache**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/styles/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header clearfix">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
          {{^authenticated}}
          <li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
          {{/authenticated}}
          {{#authenticated}}
          <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="var f=document.createElement('form');f.method='POST';f.action='/logout';f.submit();">Logout</a></li>
          {{/authenticated}}
        </ul>
      </nav>
<img id="logo" src="/images/perfect-logo-2-0.png" width="176" height="58" alt="Perfect Logo">

      <h3 class="text-muted"><a href="/">Perfect Swift Secure File Upload</a></h3>
    </div>
    {{#flash}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
      {{flash}}
    </div>
    {{/flash}}
```

**index.mustache**

```
{{>header}}

{{^authenticated}}
<h1>Hi! Sign up today!</h1>
{{/authenticated}}

{{>footer}}
```

**loggedin.mustache**

```
{{>header2}}


<h2>File uploads</h2>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
File to upload: <input type="file" name="fileup"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload files now.">
</form>
<code>{{#files}}{{aID}}{{/files}}</code>
<h3>Files:</h3>
{{#files}}<a href="/uploads/{{#files}}{{aID}}{{/files}}/{{name}}">{{name}}</a><br>{{/files}}
{{>footer}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the following section:

```
var authenticationConfig = AuthenticationConfig()
authenticationConfig.include("/api/v1/check")
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/login")
authenticationConfig.exclude("/api/v1/register")
```

This is where you can actively include or exclude checking of auth state.

The routes you want to exclude from auth checking should always have a home route and a login/register. Then you can specifically include routes, or use a wildcard.